# Sound card config discrepency between pi and root

Tags: raspbian, alsa

I am trying to configure a USB microphone plugged into Raspberry Pi 3 running **Raspbian Jessie**.

Before I made any changes to the system, I used `amixer` to inspect the situation, both for the regular user `pi` and for superuser `root`:

```
$ amixer
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback -10239 - 400
  Mono: Playback -1926 [78%] [-19.26dB] [on]

$ sudo amixer
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback -10239 - 400
  Mono: Playback -1926 [78%] [-19.26dB] [on]
```

Then, I put the following lines into the file `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` to fix the microphone's sound card at index 0:

```
options snd_usb_audio index=0
options snd_bcm2835 index=1

options snd slots=snd_usb_audio,snd_bcm2835
```

After reboot, I used `amixer` to inpsect the situation again, for `pi` and `root`:

```
$ amixer
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback -10239 - 400
  Mono: Playback -1925 [78%] [-19.25dB] [on]

$ sudo amixer
Simple mixer control 'Mic',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cvolume-joined cswitch cswitch-joined
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: Capture 0 - 16
  Mono: Capture 8 [50%] [11.90dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Auto Gain Control',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
```

**Why did they become different? It seems `root` has picked up the new config, but `pi` hasn't. How do I make them the same again? What is happening here?**